# range of size of signed int

Tags: c, range

i was thinking about size of int(signed and unsigned). The size of unsigned integer is very obvious to calculate but when it came to signed i got confused.. like if int is of 2 bytes and 15th byte is for sign then its size is 32767 thats understandable .. but when i tried to calculate the -ve minimum i did this 1 1111111111111..(16 ones). ignoring the signed bit(16th) the value was still 32767 so i got range +32767 to -32767(and thats not the right range) .
or maybe this is not the right way to calculate the range because compiler will take it as -1.

so how +32767 to -32768 is calculated ??

Comment: how it should calculated mathematically

Comment: Your machine is probably using twos complement representation.

Comment: @jxh Yeah, an that's not what OP is asking.

Comment: Questions for you: how many ints does these have : `-1 to 1` ,
`-32767 to +32768`  and `-32767 to +32767` ?

Comment: @P0W It is not an "exclusive versus inclusive interval boundaries" problem either. OP has a wrong assumption about how 2's complement is represented.

Answer (score 0):

> but when i tried to calculate the -ve minimum i did this 1 1111111111111..(16 ones). ignoring the signed bit(16th) the value was still 32767 so i got range +32767 to -32767(and thats not the right range)

Well, it **can be** the right range if your architecture defines the negative range the same way you do: that is, if it uses a ["sign and magnitude"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) (or "sign and absolute value") representation.

That's completely valid: in C, signed integers are **NOT** necessarily represented using 2's complement (as you seem to assume).

---

If your platform, however, does indeed use 2's complement, then your method for calculating the minimal negative value is incorrect. Then you have to **count backwards,** from `1111 1111 1111 1111` (which is -1), until `1000 0000 0000 0000`, which turns out to be -32768.

This is true because all of the 15 bits are changing (only the 0th bit, the sign bit stays the same as you can see), so there are `2 ^ 15` possible variations, and if you start from -1, you will arrive at -32768.

Answer (score 0):

For twos complement representation, the negation of a number is achieved by taking the complement of the number and then adding 1. So, the number `0xFFFF` complemented is `0x0000`, and adding 1 yields `0x0001`. So in twos complement, -1 is represented by the binary value of all bits set.

The largest positive signed 16 bit number is `0x7FFF`, and its negative representation is `0x8001`. Looking at that negative number, you can see that by subtracting one more from that value, we get negative number of one larger magnitude: `0x8000`.

So, `32767 = 0x7FFF`, and `-32768 = 0x8000`.

Comment: so by this logic i can get even more negative numbers... just keep subtracting 1

Comment: Except you run out of bits, so you get signed integer overflow, which leads to undefined behavior. But, in general (i.e., mathematically speaking), that is how you form sequentially negative numbers of larger magnitude. You subtract 1.

Comment: or it can be like this....in the positive side 0-32767(32768 numbers) so same amount of numbers will be in negative range too. 32767=0111 1111 1111 1111.  now -32767=(it will be in 2's complenent) 1000 0000 0000 0001. and in the negative side -1 to -32767=32767 numbers so there will be one more number that is -32768 and same amount of number on both sides .

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you have understood my answer correctly.

Comment: You will often see in `<limits.h>` for a twos complement system that `INT_MIN` is defined as `(-INT_MAX - 1)`.

Comment: Thats also a way of saying the same thing. I often forget that in the positive side there is a 0 so this (-INT_MAX-1=(-32767-1)) is just for making things balanced on both sides and thats why -32768 is automatically inserted just because of this 0 in positive side.

Comment: On a signed magnitude system, 0 may be allowed to have the negative bit set. The hardware treats `0x8000` and `0x0000` to be both 0. So, literally, `-0 == 0`. On twos complement, `-0` computes to `0x0000`, and `-INT_MIN` computes to `0x8000`. So, you can think of `0` and `INT_MIN` as special cases where the negation operation yields the same value (instead of a value with the opposite sign).